# I can't open the excel file returned by response

Tags: java, spring-boot

I used a server-side program to write an excel file to the response, but the program returned an excel file that cannot be opened normally.
After testing, I found the following situations:

1. Everything works fine when the server-side program runs on the local windows environment, but the file returned when running on the linux test environment cannot be opened.
2. Even the excel file downloaded by curl in the linux test environment cannot be opened.
3. The file is normal when saved directly without using response, confirming that there is a problem when writing to response.
4. The file size returned when an exception occurs is larger than normal.

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String fn = fileName + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".xlsx";

String utf = "UTF-8";

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding(utf);
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=30");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fn, utf));
```

I tried to change the encoding or the font of the excel file, hoping to get a normal return, but the returned file still cannot be opened.

Comment: Did you check the content of the downloaded file with a hex editor and compared it to the "working" file?

Comment: xlsx files are actually zip files. Rename it to .zip and open it, and you can compare the contents with a working xlsx file. Also, what is the error message given by excel when trying to open the file?

Comment: the writing of the response looks fine to me. adding to the comment of @knittl  you could check the [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Answer (score 0):

I find the bug.An additional interceptor on the server intercepted my response and converted it into a string, which resulted in file corruption